# what is wrong with calling the help function?

Tags: python-3.x, function

I have problems calling the help function on the pd.read_csv()

pandas is already imported as pd

```
import pandas as pd
help(pd.read_csv())
```

and I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#21>", line 1, in <module>
    help(pd.read_csv())
TypeError: parser_f() missing 1 required positional argument: 'filepath_or_buffer'
```

What is wrong with my help call?

Comment: `help` wants a function, not a result of a function. Try `help(pd.read_csv)`

Answer (score 2):

in `help(pd.read_csv())` you first called `pd.read_csv()` (cause of the parenthesis) so the interpreter was expecting an argument for, to execute it and return its result and pass it as argument to `help`.

The `help` function accepts functions as arguments so to show help execute `help(pd.read_csv)`.

`pd.read_csv` is the function, `pd.read_csv()` is a call to that function.

Answer (score 1):

Quite simply: don't **call** the object you want help on. Here:

```
help(pd.read_csv())
```

The parents after `pd.read_csv` are the function call operator. You don't want to *call* this function, you want to pass it as argument to `help()`, ie:

```
help(pd.read_csv)
```